# Unhandled promise rejection but no obvious asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, expo

This one has me stumped because I do not see where the asynchronous part is coming into it. Im getting a `Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: copyOfWatchList]` error but other than the code sitting inside an async function, this particular piece of code isnt asynchronous I would have thought.

All it is doing is making a copy of an array state obj `this.state.symbols` and then adding a new key/value pair into a specific point in the obj, which works. The various `console.log` lines all display correct data.

Im then trying to copy the new obj back into the array at a specific point `i` where it says `copyOfWatchList[i] = theNewWatchListData` but this line throws the above error.

Why? How do I fix this?

```
 onPressAlertListItem = async (item) => {
   .....
   A WHOLE BUNCH OF ASYNC CODE THAT IS SEPERATE FROM BELOW AND WORKS ON ITS OWN
  ........

          var copyofWatchList = [...this.state.symbols];
          [...OTHER CODE WHICH DETERMINES THE VALUE OF newStuff...]
          for (var i = 0; i < copyofWatchList.length; i++) {
            theNewWatchListData = {
              ...copyofWatchList[i],
              newKey: newStuff
            };
            //console.log(theNewWatchListData) //this line works and has the added newKey:newStuff key value pair added to the object
            //save the array obj back into the watch list
            copyOfWatchList[i] = theNewWatchListData; //this line throws an error Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: copyOfWatchList]
            //console.log(copyofWatchList[i]) //this line works if the above line is commented out
          }
}
```

Comment: This is just a typho. Check the case of the variable on which it throws error.

Comment: Is `theNewWatchListData` declared?

Comment: Thanks @Panther I was staring at it for ages. Even VSCode showed it highlighted as the same name. Wonder why it doesnt distinguish between case.